# ConnectionStrings: Gravar no app.config ou no registro do windows?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Minha dúvida é referente à qual a melhor maneira de manter o `ConnectionString` do meu sistema em disco para ser lido conforme a necessidade, ou seja, qual é a melhor maneira de fazer isso, gravando-o no arquivo `app.config`, ou gravando no ***registro*** do `Windows`?

Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de cada um?

Observação: Eu criei `DLLs` que Criptografam o meu `ConnectionString`, e estou trabalhando em duas `DLLs` que vão me auxiliar na conexão com o banco de dados, mas preciso saber qual lugar gravar o `ConnectionString` já criptografado, onde é mais seguro, etc.

Enfim, é uma dúvida aparentemente boba, mas que me deixou curioso. 
Hoje estou fazendo baseado no ***registro*** do `Windows`, mas, novamente, gostaria de tirar a dúvida de qual é melhor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quanto menos pontos de configuração você tiver, menos complexo será seu código e mais fácil de instalar e manter o aplicativo. Sendo assim, provavelmente você terá mais coisas do que a string de conexão no seu app.config, distribuir isso ou criar classes de criptografia so aumenta a complexidade, tendo de manter dois lugares distintos para manutenção. Outra coisa, o registro do windows é um local relativamente delicado, você não deveria ter que se preocupar com ele quando le string de conexão, nem quando faz um backup das configurações do seu ambiente de produção, bastaria copiar um arquivo de texto (criptografado ou não).

Se você implementa estratégias de publicação como Integração continua ou entrega continua, você percebe muito claramente a vantagem que isso representa ao disponibilizar uma nova versão. Visto que publicar uma versão deve ser algo simples e rotineiro.

Isso é bem discutido aqui:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803188/encrypting-connectionstrings-section-utility-for-app-config (inglês).

Se não quiser usar a estratégia discutida ai, pode simplesmente usar as ferramentas de criptografia do .net para gerar a string criptografada e guardar em um key do app.config fazendo isso em seu instalador e usando algum algoritmo de criptografia reversivel. Você não precisa implementar isso, o .net implementa esses recursos desde a versão 2.0 do framework, basta configurar o .config com uma sessão protegida e mudar seu código para algo do tipo:

```
static void ToggleConfigEncryption(string exeConfigName)
{
    // Takes the executable file name without the
    // .config extension.
    try
    {
        // Open the configuration file and retrieve 
        // the connectionStrings section.
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.
            OpenExeConfiguration(exeConfigName);

        ConnectionStringsSection section =
            config.GetSection("connectionStrings")
            as ConnectionStringsSection;

        if (section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
        {
            // Remove encryption.
            section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
        }
        else
        {
            // Encrypt the section.
            section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(
                "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
        }
        // Save the current configuration.
        config.Save();

        Console.WriteLine("Protected={0}",
            section.SectionInformation.IsProtected);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Você pode ler as instruções (documentação) detalhadas de como fazer isso aqui:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4